Intellij IDEA не даёт выбрать jdk-11
Пытаюсь создать проект в Intellij IDEA через Sping Initializr. Сначала буквально на секунду появляется правильный вариант (Java 11):

Но буквально через секунду правильный вариант исчезает и вместо него отображается Java 22:

Если посмотреть список версий, то там их 3: 17, 21, 22:

но нужной мне 11-ой нет.
При попытке выбрать 17-ую естественно получаю ошибку:

В настройках проекта везде выставил 11 версию:


В JAVA_HOME прописана 11 версия:

Invalidate Caches тоже пробовал сделать:

Версия IDEA 2021.1.3 :

Причём раньше всё работало. Но потом я попробовал скачать и поставить jdk-17 , создал на нём 2 проекта , потом удалил 17-ую версию. Вернулся на 11-ую. Но студия не даёт теперь проект создать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Если это Linux, Idea установлена из flatpac, и jdk 11 установлено куда-то в системные папки (не в пределах папки пользователя), то idea этот jdk не увидит. В этом случае может помочь установка jdk просто распаковкой из архива где-нибудь в папке пользователя. Или установка идеи с официального сайта из архива или установка через snap.

@insolor,  кажется я жёстко тупанул. Походу сам Spring Initializr не поддерживает больше версии ниже 17.

кажется я жёстко тупанул. Походу сам Spring Initializr не поддерживает больше версии ниже 17.
